# What should I change in the definition of a function to make it time dependent $f \to f(t)$?

Tags: functions, soft-question, definition

Suppose I have a function that takes from sets $X \subset \mathbb{R}$, $Y \subset\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$

$$d: X \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$$

The elements are identified by $d(x,y) = xy \in \mathbb{R}$

**Now I make a change**, and treat $x,y$ as quantities that depends on time $t$

So $d(x(t),y(t)) = x(t)y(t)$

How should change the original definition of the function $$d: X \times Y \to \mathbb{R}?$$

I am thinking of something like $$d: (X \times \mathbb{R}) \times (Y \times \mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$$

---

**Update: Case 2:**  Suppose instead I have:

$X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $Y \subset\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$

$$d: X \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$$

The elements are identified by $d(x,y) = x^Ty \in \mathbb{R}$

Similarly, I make a change and treat $x,y$ as quantities that depends on time $t$

So $d(x(t),y(t)) = x(t)^Ty(t)$

How should change the original definition of the function $d$?

Comment: So now $x,y$ are both functions of time: $x: \mathbb(R)\to X$, $y: \mathbb(R)\to Y$. As a result you have a function $x\times y: \mathbb{R}\to X\times Y$ which is $t\mapsto (x(t), y(t))$. You final function is now $d\circ (x\times y)$ which is a function $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole thing actually becomes a function $d':\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ (don't call two different functions $d$, just don't). The resoning is simple: You input a real number ($t$), and the function outputs a real number (the value of $d$ at $(x(t),y(t))$).

If you want to retain the information that this function actually goes via $X\times Y$, then you do that by writing it as a composition:
$$
\Bbb R\overset{x\,\times\, y}{\longrightarrow}X\times Y\overset{d}{\longrightarrow}\Bbb R
$$

Comment: Hi I have updated with a second scenario, in case the first scenario introduces some loss of generality

Comment: @BeachedWhale The second case doesn't really change my answer at all.